# How do you solve $2^{x-1}=\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

> $2^{x-1}=\frac{1}{x}$

Clearly by substitute $x=1$ we were able to solve this problem but how do we really solve it using calculus?

Comment: If you are familiar with numerical methods, there are a few methods which can solve your problem...

Comment: Correction, there are a few methods which can *approximate the solution for* your problem.

Comment: Just because a problem is easy to write does not make it easy to solve.  If you haven't already been introduced to a specific form of an equation in your studies and the equation you are interested in mixes sums and/or products of pieces of different "types", in this case mixing a polynomial times an exponential (*after having rearranged to $x\cdot 2^x = 2$*), then it is very likely that any such solution will be non-elementary and involve things *like* [the Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) if such useful nonelementary functions for this are even named.

Comment: (Assuming $x\in\mathbb Z$) $\log_2(1/x)=\log_2(1)-\log_2(x)=x-1\implies \log_2(x)=1-x$. Now clearly $x>0$, but also $x\leqslant 1$ or else $x>1$ on the RHS implies $x<1$ on the LHS, contradiction. Thus, you must show that $x\notin (0,1)$ to prove $x=1$ is the only solution. Begin by letting $x=1/n$ for $n>1$. What happens when $n\to \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbolic solution, using the Lambert W function.  Recall: $xe^x = y \Longleftrightarrow W(x) = y$.

$$
2^{x-1} = \frac{1}{x}
\\
x2^x=2
\\
xe^{x\log 2} = 2
\\
x\log 2 e^{x\log 2} = 2\log 2
\\
x\log 2 = W(2\log 2)
\\
x = \frac{W(2\log 2)}{\log 2}
$$

An easily proved identity is:
$$
W(z\log z) = \log z, \qquad z>1
$$
(where we choose the only real branch of $W$ in that region).

Answer (score 1):

For $x > 0$, $1/x$ is monotonically decreasing and $2^{x-1}$ is monotonically increasing, and as you point out they are equal when $x = 1$. So that's the only solution for $x>0$.

For $x < 0$, $1/x < 0 $ and $2^{x-1} > 0$, so they are never equal.

So $x = 1$ is the only solution.